# Breakpoints that conditionally break when a pointer to a base class points to a specific subclass

Tags: c++, oop, debugging, visual-studio-2015, conditional-breakpoint

Is there any proper way to set a conditional breakpoint in Visual Studio 2015 such that it breaks whenever a pointer to a base class points to a specified subclass ***type***? (see example screenshot below)

I don't want to have to spend time writing debug utility code for this, nor do I want to hack virtual table data.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to do it:

Add below as your breakpoint condition in your IDE:

```
dynamic_cast<DerivedClassYouWantToBreak*>(ptr.get())
```

Or add below code to your code and compile:

```
if (dynamic_cast<DerivedClassYouWantToBreak*>(ptr.get()))
{
    int breaksHere = 0; // put breakpoint here
}
```

Comment: You just said what to write in the conditional breakpoint's test.

Comment: See that requires me to write code and recompile and then recompile again if I want to change the type of derived class.
Right now the breakpoint condition I'm using is something like *
 (void**)ptr.get() != <pointer to the vtable of the subclass I want>
But this is very hacky and the pointer will likely change for the next run

Comment: @bigD as Blindy suggested change your breakpoint condition in your IDE to `dynamic_cast<DerivedClassYouWantToBreak*>(ptr)`